# Form inline CSS without using any CSS library

Tags: html, css

I have a form as follows.

[image]

I want to align all the labels on right side and also the colons after labels should also be aligned(must appear in same vertical line)
I don't want to use any CSS Libraries like  Bootstrap etc.

I am getting now as follows:
[image]

Comment: either create a fiddle or share the code... what u have done so far...
what i understand you want is to set the css property of `lable` to `float:right` along with `display:inline`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible try like this

```
<div style="width:100%">
   <div style="width:20%; float:left;">
       <label>Name</label>
   </div>
   <div style="width:80%; float:left;">
      <input type="text">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not too clear, but do you want something like this?

```css
.inputblock {
  display: inline-block;
  background:#f1f1f1;
  padding:1em;
}
.row {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 2px 0;
}
.row input, .row select {
  border-radius:.25em;
  width:20em;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputblock">
  <div class="row">
    <label for="firstname">First name:</label>
    <input name="firstname" id="firstname">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="lastname">Last name:</label>
    <input name="lastname" id="lastname">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="state">State:</label>
    <select id="state">
     <option>Australia</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#contact_form label {
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
}
```

`<label>` is inline by default